# Помогите сократить код на Haskell пожалуйста

Tags: функции, haskell

Надо найти все множества анаграмм, которые содержат в себе наибольшее количество слов.

Функция должна иметь следующий тип:

```hs
anagram :: [String] -> [[String]]
```

Пример:

```hs
GHCi> anagram ["abc", "hehe", "foo", "cba", "eheh", "hhee", "oof", "ofo"]
[["eheh","hehe","hhee"],["foo","ofo","oof"]]
```

То есть в вывод идут только самые длинные списки, в данном случае состоящие из 3 слов
Код в одну строку и символов не более 100

Это было само задание, такой код получился:

```
anagram lst =  let {t = map (nub. map snd) $ groupBy (\(l,_) (r,_) -> l == r) $ sortOn fst $  map (\s -> (sort s,s)) lst;  cmax = maximum $ map length t} in  filter (\l -> cmax == length l) t
```

Он не проходит по длине, (если что `import Data.List` прописывать не нужно), заранее спасибо

Comment: Ваше решение не только про длине не подходит, оно и не работает правильно. Попробуйте запустить хотя бы с тем параметром, который вы сами привели в качестве примера. Получается ожидаемый вывод?

Comment: Я, честно говоря, на Haskell первый раз пишу, это для задания по CTF надо, по инструкции гугла писал, не разбираюсь особо, помогите пожалуйста правильно написать)

Comment: @CyberSecurity смотрите в сторону упорядочивания букв в словах, и последующей группировки всех слов, имеющих одинаковый одинаковый вид после такого упорядочивания.

Comment: Проверяющая система приняла все тесты, но пишет длинна слишком большая: ```anagram lst =  let {t = map (nub. map snd) $ groupBy (\(l,_) (r,_) -> l == r) $ sortOn fst $  map (\s -> (sort s,s)) lst;  cmax = maximum $ map length t} in  filter (\l -> cmax == length l) t``` @Fyodor Soikin @extrn

Comment: У меня получилось такое решение `anagram = last . f length . f sort . nub where f = ...`. Вам остается реализовать f

Answer (score 0):

**Во-первых**: необязательно сначала ставить каждое слово в пару с его отсортированной версией, потом группировать по первому элементу, а потом его выбрасывать. Можно сразу группировать по отсортированной версии.

```
Было:  map (nub. map snd) $ groupBy (\(l,_) (r,_) -> l == r) $ sortOn fst $  map (\s -> (sort s,s)) lst

Стало: groupBy (\a b -> sort a == sort b) $ sortOn sort lst
```

Это, правда, приведёт к потере производительности, потому что каждое слово будет сортироваться по нескольку раз. Но в вашем вопросе производительность не упоминается, а упоминается только длина кода, так что именно в эту сторону я и оптимизирую.

**Во-вторых**: если ваша цель короткий код, то лямбда-выражения можно сократить с помощью функций-комбинаторов. Например, `f a == f b` можно выразить как `` (==) `on` f ``. Правда функцию `on` придётся импортировать из `Data.Function` - не знаю, отвечает ли это вашим правилам.

```
Было:  \a b -> sort a == sort b
Стало: (==) `on` sort
```

То же самое со вторым лямбда-выражением:

```
Было:  \l -> cmax == length l
Стало: (cmax ==) . length
```

**В-третьих**: если ваша цель короткий код, то выбирать многобуквенные идентификаторы - это самоубийство.

```
Было:  cmax
Стало: m
```

**В-четвёртых**: пробелы. Они на фиг не нужны (в основном), но отнимают кучу места.

```
Было:  anagram lst =  let {t = groupBy ((==) `on` sort) $ sortOn sort lst;  m = maximum $ map length t} in  filter ((m ==) . length) t

Стало: anagram lst=let{t=groupBy((==)`on`sort)$ sortOn sort lst;m=maximum$ map length t}in filter((m==).length)t
```

Уже 106 символов. Почти.

**В-пятых**: `map` можно заменить на его операторную форму `<$>`. Количество символов то же, но можно сэкономить два пробела с двух сторон.

```
 Было:  map length t
 Стало: length<$>t
```

**В-шестых**: последний вызов `filter` можно записать в виде list comprehension (не знаю как это по-русски) и получится короче:

```
 Было:  filter((m ==).length)t
 Стало: [x|x<-t,length x==m]
```

**И наконец**: `` (==) `on` sort `` можно заменить на `on(==)sort` и тем сэконочить две обратные кавычки.

```
 Было:  (==)`on`sort
 Стыло: on(==)sort
```

И вуаля: 100 символов!

```
anagram lst=let{t=groupBy(on(==)sort)$ sortOn sort lst;m=maximum$ length<$>t}in [x|x<-t,length x==m]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое